# How to retain the original shape of an 2d array in python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have a set of X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test datasets generated using scikit learn.
The original shape of these sets is as below:

```
X_train-shape (669, 50)
y_train-shape (669, 50)
X_test-shape (167, 50)
y_test-shape (167, 50)

print(X_train[0:2])

[[2533  295 1497 2464  602 1257 1663  929 2804 1161  690  602  469 1054
  2638 2690 1411 2638 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312
  3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312
  3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312 3312]
 [1159 3183 3010  962 3246  602 2162 2564  602  193  678 3250   30  602
  3255 1257 2945 1269 2698 2888  602  469 1930 2381 1269 2832 1888 2596
   422 2543 3294  602 2678  909  193 2953 2381 1971 1565  693 1411 2596
   469 3185 1906 1574  286 2979 2596   54]]
```

On the training dataset, I am applying a pre-processing logic to delete an instance of a number if it is present consecutively. Below is the code for that logic:

```
X_train_new=[]
y_train_new=[]
for i,j in zip(X_train, y_train):
  a,b=remove_repeatitions(i, j)
  X_train_new.append(a)
  y_train_new.append(b)

X_train_new_01=np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in X_train_new])
y_train_new_01=np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in y_train_new])


def remove_repeatitions(document, tags):
    i=0 
    j=0
    doc_list=list(document)
    tags_list=list(tags)
    while i < len(tags)-3:
       if (tags[i] == tags[i+1]) & (tags[i] == tags[i+2]): #& (tags[i] == tags[i+3]):
          del tags_list[(i-j)]
          del doc_list[(i-j)]
          j=j+1
        else:
          pass;    
      i = i+1
    
    return(doc_list, tags_list)
```

But after this pre-processing the shape of X_train_new_01 and y_train_new_01 gets changed to just (669,) which fails further with an error

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

when I use them to run the below code (neural network code using BiLSTM)

```
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint("model_weights.h5", monitor='val_loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='min')
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='max', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False)
callbacks = [PlotLossesCallback(), chkpt, early_stopping]
history = model.fit(
    x= X_train_new_01,
    y= y_train_new_01,
    validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
    batch_size=32, 
    epochs=60,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    verbose=1)
```

Please advise how can I fix this error.

Comment: Firstly, don't ever delete items from a list or numpy array looping forwards. This will cause  plenty of index problems, and you will miss items which should be deleted. To get rid of your specific error, you can use `np.squeeze` to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Did you get a "ragged array" warning when doing `X_train_new_01=np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in X_train_new])`?   What is the `dtype` of this array?  I suspect that when doing delete, you changed the length of some of the rows of `x_train`, so they are not long all (50,).  It can't make a 2d array from that.

Comment: @hpaulj, I didn't get any error or warning. the dtype is object. Yes, the length of rows in X_train is not the same (50) anymore. I understand it is weird, but I have this requirement to apply this data pre-processing on the training set only. Can you please advise any other approach for this problem by looking at my code?

Comment: @ZWang, by looking at my code, could you please advise where I should apply the np.squeeze ?

Comment: @tanmay On the `doc_list, tags_list` after calling the function `remove_repeatitions`